# How do you set the y-axis width on a Flex Chart

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, charts

When using a Flex chart, the y-axis is drawn as a thick (about 8px) grey line. Is it possible to change this to be just a thin line like the x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You need to set your own LineSeries with a custom SolidColorStroke that you specify.